# How to control the execution of a python subprocess

Tags: python-3.x, concurrency, subprocess

I want to stop and resume the execution of a subprocess at given points in time(code).

My main program generates several batches of output and I want to evaluate them with a third party tool. Unfortunately each batch is dependent on the evaluation of the last batch, so I can't simply run my program and than the evaluator, I have to run
main, evaluator, main, evaluator, main, evaluator

Now there are two problems:

1. the evaluator has a huge overhead, that I can not afford to run every single  time
2. my program and the evaluator both use tensorflow and crash when used in the same process

so I need something like this:

```
def main():
    s = subprocess.Popen()
    while True:
        generate_batch()
        send_batch_is_ready_signal()
        wait_for_subprocess()

def subprocess():
    huge_overhead()
    while True:
        wait_for_next_batch()
        evalaute_batch()
        send_evaluation_is_ready_signal()
```

currently I use files to send signals
i create a file to send a signal and wait_for simple looks for it and deletes it once found, is there a better way to do this?
thank you very much :)